# Insert dictionary key and values to a python list

Tags: python

I was trying to insert key and value of my dictionary to a python list.I cant seem to figure it out how to do this.

```
my_dict={test1:[1,2,3,4],test2:[2,3,4,5]}
```

what I want is

```
my_list = [['test1', 1,2,3,4], ['test2', 2,3,4,5]]
```

I am new to python so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @Rakesh Your code gave me this as output
[[test1, [1,2,3,4]], [test2, [2,3,4,5]]]
my_list = [[k, v[0],v[1],v[2],v[3]] for k, v in status_list_dict.items()]
This worked for me.Thanks for the help though :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This should do it
We need to iterate over the dictionary, and make a list with the key and values, note that we need to unroll the value array `*value` in order to append to the list

```
my_dict={'test1':[1,2,3,4],'test2':[2,3,4,5]}

#Iterate over key and value, and make a list from them, unrolling the value since it is a list
my_list = [[key, *value] for key, value in my_dict.items()]
print(my_list)
#[['test1', 1, 2, 3, 4], ['test2', 2, 3, 4, 5]]
```

Answer (score 5):

Using a list comprehension

**Ex:**

```
my_dict={"test1":[1,2,3,4],"test2":[2,3,4,5]}

my_list = [[k] +v for k, v in my_dict.items()]
print(my_list)
```

**Output:**

```
[['test1', 1, 2, 3, 4], ['test2', 2, 3, 4, 5]]
```

Answer (score 3):

The other solutions use list comprehensions which may be too complicated for someone who is new to python, so this is a solution without list comprehension.

```py
my_dict={"test1":[1,2,3,4],"test2":[2,3,4,5]}

new_list = []
for key, value in my_dict.items():
    print(key, value)

    temp = []
    temp.append(str(key))
    for a in value:
        temp.append(a)
    new_list.append(temp)

print(new_list) 
# [['test1', 1, 2, 3, 4], ['test2', 2, 3, 4, 5]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a version without the list comprehension, I remember it took me a couple months to understand the syntax when I was new to python.

```py
my_dict={'test1':[1,2,3,4],'test2':[2,3,4,5]}

my_list = []

for key, value in my_dict.items():
    my_list.append([key, *value]) # the '*value' bit means all elements of the 'value' variable

print(my_list)
```

Comment: I had the same solution in a first try @reportgunner

Answer (score 1):

FOMO:

```
my_dict={'test1':[1,2,3,4],'test2':[2,3,4,5]}
x = lambda a:[a[0],*a[1]]; print([x(i) for i in my_dict.items()])
#[['test1', 1, 2, 3, 4], ['test2', 2, 3, 4, 5]]
```